# Iteration in Cogrouped second tuple CompactBuffer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two key value Pair `rdd's A and B`, data looks like

```
A={(1,(1,john,CA)),
(2,(2,steve,NY)),
(3,(3,jonny,AL)),
(4,(4,Evan,AK)),
(5,(5,Tommy,AZ))} 

B={(1,(1,john,WA)),
(1,(1,john,FL)),
(1,(1,john,GA)),
(2,(2,steve,NY)),
(3,(3,jonny,AL)),
(4,(4,Evan,AK)),
(5,(5,Tommy,AZ))}
```

Rdd `B` has three values for the key `1` so while applying `cogroup`

```
c = A.cogroup(B).filter { x => ((x._2._1) != (x._2._2)) }.collect() we get 

c = {(1,CompactBuffer(1,john,CA),CompactBuffer(1,john,WA,1,john,FL,1,john,GA)}
```

Collecting two `CompactBuffers` in two variables like below

```
d = c.map(tuple =>(tuple._2._1.mkString("")))
e = c.map(tuple =>(tuple._2._2.mkString("")))
```

Iterating `d`and `e` like below

```
for(x <-d)
{
  for(y <-e){

  println(x +" source and destination "+ y)
  }
}
```

**Expected output**

```
1,john,CA  source and destination  1,john,WA
1,john,CA  source and destination  1,john,FL
1,john,CA  source and destination  1,john,GA
```

**Output received**

```
1,john,CA source and destination 1,john,WA,1,john,FL,1,john,GA
```

What I should change for Iterating the `Second Tuple elements i.e Second Compactbuffer()`

Kindly Let me know if you have any doubts or clarification in question.

Comment: The length of array returned by `e = c.map(tuple =>(tuple._2._2.mkString("")))` would be `1` because you are using `mkString`. So `d` and `e` will only have one value each.

Comment: If I remove `mkString()`  its printing like `CompactBuffer(1,john,CA) source and destination CompactBuffer(1,john,WA,1,john,FL,1,john,GA)`

Comment: Tr `val e = c.map(tuple => tuple._2._2).flatMap(identity)` and same for `d` and then run your for loops

Comment: @philantrovert, please answer below your suggestion :) I tried it and it works :)

Comment: @philantrovert, Thank you its working..! Answer below so I can Accept it

Comment: you don't need map and flatMap. You can just use flatMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments , `mkString` was converting your array to an array of one element. You can alternatively evaluate your lazy iterator by converting it to an Array and then iterating over it :

```
c.foreach { x =>
    val arr1 = x._2._1.toArray
    val arr2 = x._2._2.toArray
    for (e1 <- arr1 ) {
        for (e2 <- arr2 ) {
            println (e1 + "-----------" + e2 ) 
        }
    }
 }

(1,john,CA)-----------(1,john,WA)
(1,john,CA)-----------(1,john,FL)
(1,john,CA)-----------(1,john,GA)
```

With what you had written, you can replace `mkString` with a `flatMap` operation to evaluate the iterator:

```
d = c.flatMap(tuple =>tuple._2._1)
e = c.flatMap(tuple =>tuple._2._2)
```

And then proceed with your `for` loop.

Comment: you should include both ways in your answer. please include the one you suggested in the comments of the question as well :)

Comment: @RameshMaharjan  Added.